# Where can one find the alien weapon in Fallout 2? Is it even real?

Tags: fallout-2

i heard rumors that one can get a alien weapon in Fallout 2. Is it real? How can i obtain it? Someone told me it is possible to get it during a random encounter on the map. Are there any possibilities how to increase the chance of this encounter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the corresponding [wiki page here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Blaster), it give plenty of info. Basically, in Fallout 1 this is a random special encounter, while in F2 it can be obtained both in a random special encounter, and by a specific route.

Hope this helps.